# FileSystem.CopyFile, getting Elapsed Time

Tags: c#, time, copy

I'm currently importing the using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;` in my project to utilize `FileSystem.CopyFile` like so:

`FileSystem.CopyFile(sourceFile, destFile, UIOption.AllDialogs);`

Does this library support a way to extract the elapsed time of the file copy?

Ex. Returning an int of how many seconds the transfer took?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: No.  Measuring it yourself it trivial since the method won't return until the copy is complete.

Comment: Why don't you use `System.IO.File.Copy` in C#?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman: Because VB's method does more? Most notably, include dialogs to track progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), start it, start your copy, stop the stopwatch and look at the Elapsed property.